# How to pass data from Rear_View to Front_view by delegate using SWRevealViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uicollectionview, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a SWRevealViewController and I have a UITableView in my Front_View and UICollectionView in my Rear_View. So when I tap on a Front_View Table Cell then my Rear_View will open and my requirement is when I will tap on a Rear_View Collection Cell then I want to pass index and control has to come in Front_View.

I mean according to my rear_view Collection Cell didSelect action, data would populate in my front_view. I am not able to pass data from rear_View to front_view. I tried by delegate but using SWReveal I am not able to send data.
Normally I know how to pass data by delegate.

Here is my code:

Front View:

```
//Cell For Row At IndexPath
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //Assign Cell
    let cellIdentifier:String = "SelectCategory"
    var cellFeeds:SelectCategory? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as? SelectCategory

    if (cellFeeds == nil)
    {
        var nib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SelectCategory", owner: self, options: nil)!
        cellFeeds = nib[0] as? SelectCategory
    }

    cellFeeds?.selectionStyle = .none


    //For Two cells rear View will open
    if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        //self.revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = 0.0
        self.revealViewController().rightViewRevealOverdraw = 0.0
        self.revealViewController().bounceBackOnOverdraw = false

        cellFeeds?.btnDropDown.addTarget( self.revealViewController(), action:#selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:)) , for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
    }

    return cellFeeds!
}

//Table view row select method
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Assign Cell
    let cellIdentifier:String = "SelectCategory"
    let cellFeeds:SelectCategory? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as? SelectCategory

    if(0 == indexPath.row || 1 == indexPath.row)
    {
        //Open Rear View.
        revealViewController().rightRevealToggle(animated: true)
    }
}  


//Delegate of Rear View
extension AddProductView : didTapOnSubCategory {
  func tapOnCategory(index: Int) {
      print("Index Tap is :-  \(index)")
  }
}  


//Declare the delegate
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   let vc = GetAddProductDataView()
    vc.delegate = self

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Rear_View :-

```
//Declare protocol.
protocol didTapOnSubCategory {
  func tapOnCategory(index : Int)
}  

class GetAddProductDataView: UIViewController,SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {

  //TableView
  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

  //Collection View
  @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

  //Category Label
  @IBOutlet var categoryLabel: NSLayoutConstraint!

  //Declare Delegate
  var delegate : didTapOnSubCategory?

  //View Did Load
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

    //Add Gesture to Swipe Reveal
      self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
      revealViewController().delegate = self

    //Delegate of tableView
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    //tableView.isHidden = false
    collectionView.isHidden = true
  }  
  //Select the CollectionView Cell
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     delegate?.tapOnCategory(index: indexPath.row)

     let gotoFrontView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWAddProductView") as! SWRevealViewController

    revealViewController().setFront(gotoFrontView, animated: true)
    revealViewController().frontViewPosition = FrontViewPosition.left
   }
}
```

So in my front_View and rear_view you can see that everything is fine but I am not able to pass index from rear_View (class GetAddProductDataView) to front_View.

Comment: When you are opening you rear_view at that time pass the instance of your front view to your rear_view and call protocol with same instance.

Comment: Another way is to use userdefault to store index in rear_view and get that index on frontView.

Comment: I knew that I can use NSUserDefault.
But I have to pass to much data after index that's why asked for NSUserDefault.
Thanks

Comment: It would better if you will explain me in my code. I mean what I have to do.
Thanks

Comment: I am calling by button using setting the target.
You can see in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.
Thanks

Comment: nsnotificationcenter can be used for this as well
In case you want to do via delegate, Please let me know that you are passing the current instance of your front view to rear view.

Comment: I have mentioned everything in my code.
I think I am missing something that's what not able to pass data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133339/discussion-between-kishor0011-and-abhishek-sharma).

Comment: It is showing nil delegate.
What to do?
Thanks

Comment: Any Solution ?
thanks

Comment: Please help? Still facing same problem.